# How Can I format a DATETIME in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, create-table

I need to save datetime in this columns in this format and then it will be seen in this format if i write select TIME from GAMES. But this is wrong. Can you help me ?

```
create table GAMES  (
      CIS_HRY              INTEGER                     not null,
      NAZEV                VARCHAR2(30)                not null,
      Date DATE NOT NULL   FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      TIME DATE NOT NULL   FORMAT 'HH24: MI: SS',
      POPIS                  CLOB,
   constraint PK_GAMES primary key (CIS_HRY)
);
```

Comment: You save date/time values using native formats such as dates.  You convert them to strings using `to_char()` to get a representation that you need in a query.

Comment: Sorry it can be say more dumb for me ? when I convert it ? everytime if i want select date ? Or it can be convert permanently.

Comment: You can store any format you like in strings (NVARCHAR), the oracle standard types have no format, so you need to convert it every time you select. (You could do it in a view but be carefull, it might not use the index if you want to filter or sort on the result).

Comment: Because you'll likely need to use comparison operators such as < , > , etc. it would be unwise to store dates and times as strings. As an FYI, the Oracle date datatype includes a time component, just not down to fractional seconds, as is the case with the timestamp data type. So by having one date field you have both date and time information, based on what you posted (SS is full, not fractional seconds). As gordon indicated, you can use to_char() to separate the date and time component in 2 columns, in whatever format desired, when you run your selects.

Answer (score 8):

Dates do not have a "format" in Oracle - they always contain the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. You format dates using the `TO_CHAR` function when extracting them for use in a particular situation. I suggest that you re-work your table design as

```
create table GAMES  (
      CIS_HRY              INTEGER not null,
      NAZEV                VARCHAR2(30) not null,
      CREATED_DATE_TIME    DATE NOT NULL,
      POPIS                CLOB,
   constraint PK_GAMES primary key (CIS_HRY)
);
```

When fetching data from this table you might use TO_CHAR to format the date:

```
SELECT CIS_HRY,
       NAZEV,
       TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CREATE_DT,
  FROM GAMES
  WHERE NAZEV = 'XYZ';
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you might do in this case. If you're using Oracle 11g or 12c, you could use virtual columns to "store" the date as a `VARCHAR2` in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, and time in your specified format; or you might use a trigger on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to do the same with real columns; or you might (and this is probably the best option), create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW games_v AS
SELECT cis_hry, nazev, TO_CHAR(create_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS chardate
     , TO_CHAR(create_dt, 'HH24: MI: SS') AS chartime, popis
  FROM games;
```

If you need to update the "date" and/or "time" in the `GAMES_V` view, you can do so via an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on `GAMES_V`. That might be overkill for your purposes.

By the way, I would avoid using `date` as a column name in Oracle - it's a reserved word. And you should probably avoid `time` as well - I don't think it is a reserved word, but it is generic and not very descriptive.